# Is it possible to peg a memory location to a cache

Tags: c, linux, caching, gcc, x86

It is possible that a variable in user space program is fixed to a cache location?

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed to a cache location"? (Could you maybe point at what you refer to in kernel code?)

Comment: I mean that a variable is always in the cache.

Comment: Some CPUs have the capability to lock certain regions of cache but it's a CPU-specific hardware feature and most desktop/server CPUs do not support this. I don't think there are any x86 CPUs that do, but I know that some PowerPC embedded CPUs do, for example.

Comment: Have you considered register variable?

Comment: Jack, ya I am now changing my method to use a register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@MetallicPriest, you keep **asking mysterious questions without *motivating* them** enough.....
You should **try**, when asking questions here, to ask a question with a short & precise phrase -you do that very well- and then **to motivate and give the context of your question** in a whole paragraph (you never do that, and you really should). If possible, also give pointers to the current state of your mysterious software (e.g. a public GIT repository).

AFAIK, for an application program on Linux (at least x86 or AMD64), the processor cache (if it is this cache you are speaking of) almost does not exist (i.e. is not really visible from the application point of view).

However, the process might (or not) have some machine instructions to deal with the cache. AFAIK, these are model specific (i.e. an AMD Phenom processor might behave differently than an Intel i7).

Fortunately for you, the latest **GCC compiler is able** (when optimizing) **to generate cache related instructions**. It also gives you some [**cache related builtins**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) like `__builtin___clear_cache` or  `__builtin_prefetch`. However, be aware that these builtins have imprecise meaning, and are implemented in various ways, and probably depend of your [optimization options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) and your [target specific options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html#i386-and-x86_002d64-Options) given to `gcc`

And probably the `volatile` attribute of GCC may help you w.r.t. caching (by "removing" it).

At last, a variable (in an application program on Linux) cannot always stay in the cache. For instance, since context switches are initiated by the kernel, a cache line will become used by another process (and its data) from time to time. Actually, the kernel is even sometimes moving an active process from one core to another of your multi-core desktop processor!

Comment: Some of this answer belongs in a comment.  Comments and answers are not the same thing.

Comment: Agreed, but comments are in a so small font that perhaps @MetallicPriest might not read them. And he really ask interesting but bizarre questions, without enough motivation (and sometimes with some ambiguity).

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is possible to do it in some way on most modern CPUs; either by using explicit support in the CPU (which 80x86 doesn't support), by hacks (e.g. loading it into the cache and then disabling cache line fills on modern 80x86), or by preventing other data from causing the cache line/s to be evicted via. other means (e.g. pound the daylights out of the CPU with "CLFLUSH" regularly).

However "in general" doesn't mean "for Linux specifically". I doubt Linux supports these things, especially for user-space processes.

The reason why I doubt Linux supports it is that there is no sane reason for Linux (or any other general purpose OS) to support it. If something is used regularly then it'll be in the CPU's cache anyway; and if something isn't used regularly then you don't want it to waste space in the cache and slow everything else down.

There are only really 3 sane reasons for it. The first is firmware code that runs before RAM chips are initialised (which I doubt applies here). The second reason is extreme "hard real time" where the extra latency of a cache miss can't be tolerated (which I doubt applies here and probably doesn't apply anywhere else either). The third reason is to work around special cases where the normal "least recently used" eviction policy of caches leads to problems (like cache pollution) where there's much better ways of fixing/avoiding these problems (e.g. prevent the unnecessary data from being cached, or flush it soon after it gets into the cache).

Basically, I'm suggesting that you think you might want to force something to stay in the cache, but you actually don't want to force something to stay in the cache.

Comment: Most L1/L2 caches aren't LRU, they are associative, so pollution works a lot differently (and is a lot more likely).

Comment: @SoapBox, I know - for something like a 4-way associative cache there's only 4 spots that a specific a cache line can go; and the CPU uses a "least recently used" eviction policy to determine which of the 4 possible spots to evict when it needs space for the new cache line. Of course there's a fine line between over-generalisation and over-complication, and it can be hard to find a suitable balance for the original poster that is also a suitable balance for random spectators... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry dude but as far as I know, this can't be done in user space but only in kernel space.

Comment: It has nothing to do with space of execution. it's a simple matter of CPU having (or, rather, not having) the feature.

Comment: So write a kernel space driver that user space can talk to. Memory pegged! Although this really sounds like there's better optimizations the OP should try before second guessing his CPU's cache mechanism.